How to make Outlook close to tray
Is it possible to keep Outlook open in the tray when closing the main window (by clicking the X button/ALT+F4)?

I'm a software developer and I got fed up with waiting on Microsoft to add the ability to do this, so I wrote a program to do it myself
https://github.com/Palsternakka/OutlookWindowHook
Only works with the new Outlook client (for now - if there's enough interest I'll implement support for older versions!)
Makes Outlook behave exactly like Teams - doesn't require admin privileges to install

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
